# How to find the lowest value from the list?

Tags: c#

```
 //create the new object for cars
    Cars s1 = new Cars("Toyota", 2005, 500000, "White", "good");//Car1 Ob
    Cars s2 = new Cars("Honda", 2004, 550000, "Black", "fine");//Car2 Ob
    Cars s3 = new Cars("Nissen", 2012, 490000, "Yellow", "best");//Car3 Ob
    Cars s4 = new Cars("Suzuki", 2012, 390000, "Blue", "fine");//Car4 Ob
    Cars s5 = new Cars("BMW", 2012, 1000000, "Green", "Good");//Car5 Ob

    //Create list to add objects into the memory
    List<Cars> list1 = new List<Cars>();
    list1.Add(s1);list1.Add(s2);list1.Add(s3);list1.Add(s4);list1.Add(s5);



 //cars info which has the lowest price
        double lowest_price = 0;
        foreach(Cars a in list1){
        if(a.price <= lowest_price){
            lowest_price = a.price;
            Console.WriteLine(a.price);
            }
        }//end of loop
```

That's the code which I am trying to print out the the cars info which has the lowest price. But nothing gets print out.

Comment: None of `a.price` is less then 0. `a.price <= lowest_price` is always false.

Comment: Also you are printing `a.price` - didn't you want to print `lowest_price` ?

Comment: Oh.. right!! it is always false!! Thanks!!

Comment: You should name your class with a singular, like one `Car`. A plural name might indicate some kind of collection, like many `Cars`. This is a common practice that makes your code a lot more understandable.

Comment: Usually if you are using this pattern for locating min value, you should set the control variable to maximal possible value. That way you should have at least one hit.

Answer (score 78):

Use the [LINQ `Min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352408.aspx) extension method:

```
double lowest_price = list1.Min(car => car.price);
```

Also, you didn't specify, but this will fail if you have no cars in your set with an `InvalidOperationException` indicating "Sequence contains no elements". If it's possible you have no cars, a quick update might be:

```
double lowest_price = list1.Any() ? list1.Min(car => car.price) : 0;
```

---

As to why your *current* code prints nothing it's because your initial value is `0`. No car has a value that is *negative* (or less than `0`). If you want to keep using your existing loop, change the initial value to the highest possible value:

```
double lowest_price = Double.MaxValue;
foreach(Cars a in list1){
    if(a.price <= lowest_price){
        lowest_price = a.price;
        Console.WriteLine(a.price);
    }
}//end of loop
```

Note that this has the additional side effect that if your `list1` of cars is *empty*, then the `lowest_price` value will be `Double.MaxValue`. This may or may not be a concern for you with your existing code.

If it is a concern, and *need* to return `0` if there are no cars, you can make a slight adjustment:

```
double lowest_price;
if (list1.Any()){
    lowest_price = Double.MaxValue;
    foreach(Cars a in list1){
        if(a.price <= lowest_price){
            lowest_price = a.price;
            Console.WriteLine(a.price);
        }
    }//end of loop
}
else{
    lowest_price = 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks!! i will try that out right away! This is the exact trick I learned today!! Thanks again!

Comment: Rather than using .MaxValue, -1 or other exotic values, you could also use a nullable value type: if (!lowest.HasValue || a.Price < lowest).

Answer (score 16):

You would use the Min extension on the list.

```
lowest_price = list1.Min(c => c.price);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to fix your code to work (instead of using Linq - which is the recommended approach), change this line:

```
double lowest_price = 0;
```

to this:

```
double lowest_price = double.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 4):

just based on the problem with your code: you are not going to have a lower price than 0... so you need change it to:

```
double lowest_price =  list1[0].price; 
        foreach(Cars a in list1){
        if(a.price <= lowest_price){
            lowest_price = a.price;
            Console.WriteLine(a.price);
            }
        }//end of loop
```

***Edit***: this will only work if `list1` exists and isn't empty, for general use you'd need to check `if (list1 is null || list1.Count==0)` first line.

Comment: You probably want to check to see if the list isn't empty first, or this could throw an out of range exception

Comment: @Charleh: absolutely, this is only a fix based on OP's example (when all the items been added first as showing in the code), updated.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = list1.Where((x) => x.price== list1.Min(y => y.price)).ToList();
```

This will return car info with the lowest price. Add reference `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

The other responses correctly provide a LINQ solution, but the issue with your specific code is that you are checking if the car's priced (a.price) is <= your lowest_price variable. Your lowest_price variable is instantiated with a value of 0 and according to your default car prices listed which are all greater than 0, will never validate. So your lowest_price variable will never be updated and therefore never write it's value to the console. That's what's causing your request of "nothing prints out". It's an error in your check and in your logic. Update that line to "if (lowest_price <= a.price)" to get closer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public  static int FindMin(IEnumerable<int> numbers)
    {
        Expression<Func<int, int, int>> expression = (left, right) => left < right ? left : right;
        InvocationExpression invoker = Expression.Invoke(expression,
                                   Expression.Constant(numbers.First())
                                  , Expression.Constant(numbers.ToList()[1]));

        foreach (int number in numbers.Skip(2))
        {
            invoker = Expression.Invoke(expression,
                               invoker,
                               Expression.Constant(number));
        }
        var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(invoker);
        Console.WriteLine($"Expression call tree:{lambdaExpression.ToString()}");
        return lambdaExpression.Compile().Invoke();
    }
}
```